# Boolean implies operation

Tags: boolean, lisp, common-lisp

Why does `(defun boolimplies (a b) (or (not a) b))` if called as 
`(boolimplies 'a 'b)` return `B`?

How does it arrive at this conclusion even when I don't use any boolean value (NIL,T) but just variable names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While only `t` and `nil` are booleans in Common Lisp, there are also [*generalized booleans.*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_g.htm#generalized_boolean) That is, all objects can be used as truth values, and only the symbol `nil` is false. You are passing symbols other than `nil`, which are true.

(Just to avoid any potential confusion: If you have variables `a` and `b` and want to use their values instead of symbols, just pass them unquoted.)

Comment: yes, makes sense. Its same as using anything for true and only `nil` in conditional statements.

Comment: @Rorschach Yes, exactly.

Comment: In addition: `or` doesn't specifically return `t` or `nil` - it returns the first truthy (not nil) argument. Because `(not 'a)` is `nil`, `or` returns `'b`